# iOS iPhone shows nothing when run

Tags: ios

so I followed the tutorial at

http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/

It compiles and run successfully but it only shows Fruits at the top and no items.

Same thing happened when I followed another tutorial. Does anyone know how to fix this or what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I dont think it has to do with the guide. It has to do with some settings maybe? Somehow the xcode is not connecting to the iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 0):

**brute force:**

run the code in the debugger with breakpoints on the entry and exit of every function learn what it's doing and see where it's failing.  (At least on all the functions that display data or build data to be displayed)

**optionally (since the code you linked to is 2 years (and 2 OS versions) old):**

pick the sample code from apple that does the same thing (sorry, I don't know which one off the top of my head)

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps miss some code in the **applicationDidFinishLaunching** block in the example at the link provided?

Or perhaps didn't link the FruitViewController to the view?